# Allow access only member's group and administrator

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to allow access for certain content only for specific member's user and administration.
With the following code I can't view the content when I'm logged as admin:

```
<?php
    if (is_category(4)) {
        if (!current_user_can('my-group') || !current_user_can('add_users')) {
            echo '<h1 class="entry-title">You can not access</h1><p>This content is only for Administrator and group\'s members.</p>';
        }
    } else {
?>
```

Also I tryed each condition individually, but as admin I can't view the content.

---

I tryed this example code:

```
<?php if (is_category(8)) {
    if (!current_user_can('mio-gruppo') || !user_can('administrator')) {
        echo 'you can not pass';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'you pass';
    }
?>
```

But the two conditional statement goes in conflict. If I try both separately works right

Comment: If this is your whole code you need to close your `else` statment.

Comment: I closed my else statement after the content

  <?php
   }
  ?>

Comment: I tryed this example code:

<?php 
if (is_category(8)) { 
if (!current_user_can('mio-gruppo') || !user_can('administrator')) { 
echo 'you can not pass'; 
} 
} else { 
echo 'you pass'; 
} 
?>

But the two conditional statement goes in conflict. If I try both separately works right.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be `&&` instead of `||`:

```
<?php
    if (is_category(4)) {
        if (!current_user_can('my-group') && !current_user_can('add_users')) {
            echo '<h1 class="entry-title">You can not access</h1><p>This content is only for Administrator and group\'s members.</p>';
        }
    } else {
?>
```

Alternatively make it the other way round:

```
<?php
    if (is_category(4)) {
        if (current_user_can('my-group') || current_user_can('add_users')) {
            echo 'access granted';
        } else {
            echo 'no access';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I need:

```
<?php 
if (is_category(8) && (current_user_can(array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)) || !is_user_logged_in())) { 
if (!current_user_can('mio-gruppo')) { 
echo 'you can not pass'; 
} 
} else { 
echo ' you can pass'; 
} 
?>
```